# SLD not linking to ArcGIS wms service

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, wms, sld

I need to style an ArcGIS Server 10.0 WMS Service with an SLD File. I have picked a very simple point style SLD which should style all points with one circle.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html

I have then simply defined the SLD-Path in ArcGIS Server by editing the appropriate properties. This is however not being rendered. The points are still being symbolized with the symbols defined in the mxd with which it was created. Has anyone any experience with binding SLDs to ArcGIS Server wms services who can possible see where I am going wrong?

Comment: i am facing the same issue in ArcGIS Server v. 10.8, have you got the solution ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that ArcGIS Server 10.0 currently has a bug (NIM095568) which means it isn't following the correct WMS+SLD request pattern; so it might be just that your request isn't being understood, rather than there being a problem with your your SLD.

An example of a request to an ArcGIS 10.n WMS service with external SLD is shown below:

http://gisweb.unr.edu/arcgis/services/OneGeology/NBMG_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=39.66370840865538128,-116.13087390374420238,40.95995233180237705,-114.63744574291149547&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=925&HEIGHT=802&LAYERS=US-NV_NBMG_500k_Geology&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&SLD=http%3A%2F%2Fogc.bgs.ac.uk%2Fsld%2Fnevada-example.sld&

The same request without the external SLD is:

http://gisweb.unr.edu/arcgis/services/OneGeology/NBMG_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=39.66370840865538128,-116.13087390374420238,40.95995233180237705,-114.63744574291149547&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=925&HEIGHT=802&LAYERS=US-NV_NBMG_500k_Geology&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&

Note, as in this example, there is no requirement for the [external SLD](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/sld/nevada-example.sld) to be on the same server as ArcGIS service.